# How to return multiple filtered counts from a subquery efficiently

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a table with ~5M rows that stores firmware downloads from each user. I'm trying to build a graph of the number of downloads of a specific firmware file over the last 30 days.

Although I can populate the data, it's slow to query from the database as I'm calling into it once for each result. I'm also guessing a subquery would be faster to "pre-filter" the `firmware_id` before doing the `COUNT` on each matching day.

The model.py definition is:

```py
class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    datestr = Column(Integer, default=0, index=True)
    firmware_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('firmware.firmware_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
```

`datestr` is an integer with the current yyyymmdd, e.g. 20190101.

The way I'm currently doing this is:

```py
    data = []
    now = datetime.date.today()
    for _ in range(30):
        datestr = _get_datestr_from_datetime(now)
        total = _execute_count_star(db.session.query(Client).\
                        filter(Client.firmware_id == fw.firmware_id).\
                        filter(Client.datestr == datestr))
        data.append(int(total))
        now -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

where `_execute_count_star` is defined (seemingly much faster than `.count()`) as:

```py
def _execute_count_star(q):
    count_query = q.statement.with_only_columns([func.count()]).order_by(None)
    return q.session.execute(count_query).scalar()
```

I'd ideally like to return all 30 of the day results in one query (using a subquery to filter on `firmware_id`?); at the moment the data takes about ~3s to be populated which is much too long to show to users by default. Also, the table is expected to grow at 0.5M rows per month, so the problem is only going to get worse. Any help or advice very welcome, thank you all so much.

Comment: what is the ultimate goal, you want sales per day  within the 30 day window ?  are you familiar with GROUP BY because it sounds like you just want to GROUP BY day.  this wouldn't involve a subquery or anything like that.

Comment: No, I need the number of downloads for each day, e.g. `[1,2,3,678,1293]`

Comment: this is what GROUP BY is used for.  you want "SELECT datestr, count(*) FROM clients WHERE firmware_id=<id> AND datestr BETWEEN 20190301 AND 20190401 GROUP BY datestr".     I can show you the ORM query version of that but try it out on your SQL command line.   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp